# How do I get the chevron inside a circle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

Just added the following code to my app to display a chevron inside a circle (one per each row of table view):

```
cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

But what I get is an   i   inside a circle and a chevron outside and to the right of the circle. Is there a way of getting only chevron inside a circle?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator
Look for possible accessory types for accessoryType property of UITableViewCell in documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellAccessoryType

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did as suggested but now I get a greyed out chevron instead of blue. As if it is inactive and no action can be performed on click. Any idea why that it?

Comment: oh, it seems that you were correct with your accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton. Try to remove editingAccessoryType from your cell's configuration.

Comment: Thanks once again. I think the grey colour is default now not the blue. Thanks anyway.